# How to simplify a pandas dataframe based on treshold value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Here's my dataframe

```
      A       B        C        D
1     0    0.41     0.35     0.61
2     0    0.41     0.35        0
3     0    0.21        0        0
4  0.11     0.4     0.53        0
```

I want to only display columns or rows that contains value more than 0.5, like this

```
       C        D
1    0.35     0.61
4    0.53        0
```

How suppose I should do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) for test greater values with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if match at least one value and filter in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df.gt(0.5)
df1 = df.loc[m.any(axis=1), m.any()]
print (df1)
     C     D
1  0.35  0.61
4  0.53  0.00
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a double [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). Compute a boolean mask with [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html). Then check if [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) value is True on each axis and use this for selection using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
m = df.gt(0.5)
df.loc[m.any(1), m.any(0)]
```

output:

```
      C     D
1  0.35  0.61
4  0.53  0.00
```

###### Intermediates

`m`:

```
       A      B      C      D
1  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False
4  False  False   True  False
```

`m.any(1)`:

```
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

`m.any(0)`:

```
A    False
B    False
C     True
D     True
dtype: bool
```